# Visual Studio: Shortcut or key sequence to jump to a property in the Properties Windows

Tags: .net, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut or sequence of keys for navigating directly to a property row that is not directly adjacent to the currently selected row?

I know that <kbd>F4</kbd> will open the `Properties Window`. After that, I want to move directly to a property using its name. For example, if I have selected a `*.cs` file in Solution Explorer, hit <kbd>F4</kbd>, VS will select the last property I had selected previously. I would like to move to another property quickly, perhaps by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> for `Build Action`, or <kbd>F</kbd> for `filename`.

If I remember correctly in VB6, you could type the first letter of the property name to jump to that property. Typing the same letter went to the next property in the window with the same first letter.